# Pandas: create a function to delete links

Tags: python, pandas

I necessary need a function to delete links from my  `oldText` column (more then 1000 rows) in a pandas DataFrame.
I've created it using regex, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
def remove_links(text):
    text = re.sub(r'http\S+', '', text) 
    text = text.strip('[link]') 

    return text

df['newText'] = df['oldText'].apply(remove_links)
```

I have not error, the code do just nothing

Comment: It would be interesting to know what contains the column.

Comment: What's the actual format of the `oldText` column? How are links represented? You can use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to parse the text and extract / discard URL components.

Comment: I think the regex expression is not recognized in the text. I would check that and make sure it works at the level of the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me:
CSV:

```
oldText
https://abc.xy/oldText asd
https://abc.xy/oldTe asd
https://abc.xy/oldT
https://abc.xy/old
https://abc.xy/ol
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re


def remove_links(text):
    text = re.sub(r'http\S+', '', text) 
    text = text.strip('[link]') 

    return text


df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv')
df['newText'] = df['oldText'].apply(remove_links)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
                       oldText newText
0  https://abc.xy/oldText asd     asd
1    https://abc.xy/oldTe asd     asd
2         https://abc.xy/oldT        
3          https://abc.xy/old        
4           https://abc.xy/ol
```